Get a separate stacked bar for each row in Plotly when data has name multiples
I'm using Python 3.10 with Plotly
I have a dataframe called "cluster_user_distribution_data" with around 40 rows and a varying number of columns depending on an analysis. But lets say there are four. It looks like this:
                                 Cluster 1  Cluster 2  Cluster 3  Cluster 4
Almtunaskolan                         31.4        6.2       24.8       37.6
Almunge skola                         40.1        6.2       23.6       30.2
Bergaskolan (Videskolan)              32.6        6.2       26.0       35.1
Danmarks skola                        32.2        6.2       20.2       41.3
...

From this I want to make a stacked bar plot showing the distribution between the clusters, and with different subplots grouping the users (the index names) based on sharing the same majority clusters. So far so good, it looks like this:
Fig.1 - Current stacked bar plot
But I want to make the user names anonymous, so I have renamed them based on how "large" the users are. And now the dataframe looks like this instead:
                                 Cluster 1  Cluster 2  Cluster 3  Cluster 4
Medium school                         31.4        6.2       24.8       37.6
Medium school                         40.1        6.2       23.6       30.2
Large school                          32.6        6.2       26.0       35.1
Small school                          32.2        6.2       20.2       41.3
...

And here the problem begins. Now the Plotly bar chart combines names that are the same, and since I only got three different names it now looks like this (I'e re-scaled the x-axis to show how the data now is aggregated the wrong way):
Fig.2 - Stacked bar plot with merged names
I have searched for a solution, and found a similar case in Get a separate bar for each row in Plotly when data has duplicate categories that worked for a non-stacked bar chart. But I cannot make it to work with mine. I have tried to implement it (full code in the bottom) as:
            fig.update_layout(
                    yaxis = dict(
                tickmode = 'array',
                tickvals = np.arange(0,len(y_data)),
                ticktext = y_data
                        )
                    )             

But when changing the bar to barmode="stacked" it becomes messy.
It looks like this then (showing only the first subplot):
Fig.3 - All names listed, but data still stacked wrong
The desired outcome is to make the plot looks like the Fig.2, but with the anonymous names small/medium/large school separated as in Fig.3. That is, to separated the combine data and have them stacked for each user seperately.
The code I have used is very similar to "Color Palette for Bar Chart" example at https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-bar-charts/. My current code without color manipulation and scaling etc) looks like:
        #clusters_with_majority is an array with the unique clusters that are the majority among at least one user, e.g. [0,1,3]
        #cluster_user_distribution_data_largest_cluster is a series with the majority cluster for each user      

        row_number = 1

        for i in np.sort(clusters_with_majority):
                
            x_data  = cluster_user_distribution_data.loc[cluster_user_distribution_data_largest_cluster==i]

            #sort the data to barplot in decreasing order
            x_data = x_data.sort_values(x_data.columns[i])
            
            #get the sorted index list and the data to array/list for use in the barplot loop
            y_data = x_data.index.tolist()
            x_data = x_data.values
            
            #shift the cluster in focus to the first column
            x_data[:,[0,i]] = x_data[:,[i,0]]
            
            for j in range(0, len(x_data[0])):
                for xd, yd in zip(x_data, y_data):
                    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
                        x=[xd[j]], y=[yd],
                        orientation='h',
                        marker=dict(
                            color=colors_loop[j],
                            line=dict(color='black', width=bar_plot_line_width)
                        ),
                        showlegend=False,
                    ),
                        row =  row_number,
                    col = 1,
                    )

             row_number +=1

I've tried to find more similar cases, but those that have worked have not been for stacked bars of the ones I've found.

EDIT:
I fixed it temporarily by adding a unique number to each user name (as shown below). But if anyone knows some stacked barplot magic and how to keep them separated even though having the same name I'd be happy to hear (:


In the code above row_number is undefined, I think it should be row_number = i+1 but it's an assumption, please edit the code to make it clear.

@EricLavault Thanks for pointing it out, I added it to the code. I define it before the loop and then adds one to it after each iteration. The "i" variable is not always contionously increasing, as the "clusters_with_majority" array can be e.g. [0,1,3]

Don't rename the user/index names, just add a column in your dataframe instead. Let say this column is named 'size', you can use the code that produces the Fig.1 and do something like this (for disambiguation I use variable usernames and sizes because I don't fully understand the data manipulation in your code) :
for i in np.sort(clusters_with_majority):
    # ...
    # < code adding cluster `i` dominant Bar traces to `fig` >
    # ...

    k = str(row_number) if row_number > 1 else ''

    fig.update_layout({
        f'yaxis{k}' : dict(
            tickmode='array',
            tickvals=usernames, # Cluster `i` dominant usernames (built from `df.index`)
            ticktext=sizes      # Cluster `i` dominant sizes (built from `df['size']`)
        )
    })

    row_number +=1

See for reference :

tickmode
tickvals
ticktext

